# Please rename freenas tag to truenas

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tags

There is an existing tag [[freenas]](https://serverfault.com/tags/freenas/). This refers to "FreeNAS", a Network-Attached Storage (NAS) software product which has been around for many years. Over the course of 2019-2021, the developers of this product rebranded it "TrueNAS Core". Source: https://www.truenas.com/freenas/ . Thus I think it would be wise to rename the `[freenas]` tag to be `[truenas]`, and to make "freenas" a synonym.

I am assuming that the site allows the renaming of tags, implicitly retagging all questions tagged with the old spelling to have the new spelling. If that is not possible, I guess the next best thing is to create a new tag `[truenas]`, and maybe retag some of the 394 existing questions from `[freenas]` to `[truenas]`. Cross-references in the tag wiki entries would help, also.

I do not have nearly enough reputation on this site to propose such a thing through the UI. I would appreciate it if someone with enough reputation would consider doing it based on this request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And we have zero [truenas](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/truenas) questions in the database that I can see. Nice branding strategy. This should be doable.

Comment: The answer doesn't say so, but it appears that this in fact *has* been done.